# messgaes.properties not working in IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I want to show message replace Property [summary] of class [class member.Task] cannot be null

```
Member.Task.summary.blank=Task summary must not be blank!
```

or

```
member.Task.summary.blank=Task summary must not be blank!
```

On Class messages.properties don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct I18 code is given below. Try this.

```
task.summary.blank=Task summary must not be blank!
task.summary.nullable=Task summary must not be blank!
```